# Higher lower game in Ruby

Tags: ruby, game

I finished the Ruby chapter in [*Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*](http://pragprog.com/titles/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks). It tries to make you familiar with the core concepts of several languages rather quickly. Dutifully I did all exercises, but most likely they can be improved to be more Ruby-like. I'll post my code samples one by one, so I can apply things learned in previous questions to later questions.

Day 1

> Write a program that picks a random number. Let a player guess the
>   number, telling the player whether the guess is too low or too high.

```
range = (0..10)
to_guess = range.min + rand(range.max - range.min)
guessed = false

while !guessed
    puts "Guess a number, between #{range.min} and #{range.max}"
    guess = gets
    int = guess.to_i
    if int == to_guess
        puts 'Correct!'
        guessed = true
    else
        puts int > to_guess ? 'Lower' : 'Higher'
    end     
end
```

---

After sepp2k's comments:

```
class Range
  def size
    self.end - self.begin
  end
end

range = 0..10
to_guess = range.begin + rand(range.size)
guessed = false

until guessed
  puts "Guess a number, between #{range.begin} and #{range.end}"
  guess = gets
  int = guess.to_i
  if int == to_guess
    puts 'Correct!'
    guessed = true
  else
    puts int > to_guess ? 'Lower' : 'Higher'
  end       
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of minor things:

First of all the convention in the ruby world is to use 2 spaces for indentation, not 4. It doesn't really matter much, but it's generally easier to use the style conventions that everyone uses unless you have a reason not to.

```
range = (0..10)
```

You don't actually need the parentheses here. Parentheses are not part of range syntax - the reason you usually see ranges wrapped in parentheses is that you can't call methods on ranges without them (because `0..10.foo` would be interpreter as `0..(10.foo)`).

```
to_guess = range.min + rand(range.max - range.min)
```

You should use `begin` and `end` or `first` and `last` instead of `min` and `max`. In ruby 1.8.7 `min` and `max` are inherited from `Enumerable` and will iterate the entire range in order to find the minimum/maximum, making them `O(n)`. Only in 1.9 (in 1.9.2 at least) they're overridden to work in `O(1)` time. `begin` and `end` work in `O(1)` time in all ruby versions.

I would also consider putting this into its own method as it seems like it might come in handy more than once.

```
while !guessed
```

I would write that as `until guessed` as that reads a bit nicer to me.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I noticed is that you have a throwaway variable, `guess`, in between `gets` and `int`. You can reduce some of that by simply using `guess = gets.to_i` and `if guess == to_guess`.

Also, you could use `break` instead of the `guessed` variable and `while`/`until` condition:

```
loop do
  # ...
  if guess == to_guess
    puts 'Correct!'
    break
  end
  puts int > to_guess ? 'Lower' : 'Higher'
end
```

But that is more a matter of preference, as both methods have their merits.